# Obter um único TRUE ou FALSE em várias condicionais

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de realizar o seguinte na variável `img` logo abaixo: Obter **true** se TODAS as imagens (tag img) forem ***IGUAIS***, ou **false** se UMA OU MAIS for ***DIFERENTE*** das outras. Tentei `loop for`, mas não funciona do modo esperado, pois não consegui um jeito de comparar cada índice com os demais e ***obter um único*** ***true*** OU ***false***. Diante disso, fiquei sem ideia do que fazer.

```
var img = '<img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />'; // Todas as imagens são iguais  - Daria true
var img = '<img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_2.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />'; // Uma imagem é diferente das outras - Daria false
var img = '<img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_2.jpg" />; <img src="pic_2.jpg" />'; // Duas imagens são diferentes das outras - Daria false

img = img.split(';');

for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
console.log(img[i] != img[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você começou bem na lógica, mas errou em 3 coisas:

- Quando você faz `split` vai ter alguns `img` com espaço na frente, pra remover isso basta utilizar `.trim()`. Por isso estava dando `false` no seu, porque ele comparava um sem espaço na frente com outro que tinha espaço na frente.
- Você fixou indice `[0]` no `for`, se você quiser comparar o atual com o próximo você inicializa o `for` a partir do **1** e vai comparando com o anterior.
- Utilizar uma variável pra fazer o controle se é igual ou não.

```js
var img = '<img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />'; // Todas as imagens são iguais  - Daria true
//var img = '<img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_2.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />'; // Uma imagem é diferente das outras - Daria false
//var img = '<img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_1.jpg" />; <img src="pic_2.jpg" />; <img src="pic_2.jpg" />'; // Duas imagens são diferentes das outras - Daria false

img = img.split(';');

var igual = true;
for (var i = 1; i < img.length; i++) {
  
    // se alguma for diferente então já retorna falso
    if(img[i-1].trim() != img[i].trim()) {
        igual = false;
        break;
    }
  
}

console.log(igual);
```

Agora se você quiser um exemplo mais prático para comparar os `src` das imagens, faria algo assim:

```js
function isImagensIguais() {
   var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img');
  
   for (var i = 1; i < imgs.length; i++) {
      // se alguma for diferente então já retorna falso
      if(imgs[i-1].src != imgs[i].src) {
          return false;
      }
  }
  return true;
}

window.onload = function () {
  alert(isImagensIguais());  
}
```

```html
<img src="pic_1.jpg" />
<img src="pic_1.jpg" />
<img src="pic_2.jpg" />
<img src="pic_2.jpg" />
```

Comment: @eden não seria meu primeiro exemplo?

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro usares o browser e o DOM para interpretar isso em vêz de usar `.split(';')`. De qualquer maneira deixo uma sugestão que pode ser adaptada no caso de quereres usar isso na mesma.

```
function verificar(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str;
    var imagens = div.children;
    for (var i = 0; i < imagens.length; i++) {
        if (imagens[0].src != imagens[i].src) return false
    }
    return true;
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3d384sdk/

essa função recebe uma string como tens no exemplo, insere-a numa div que é usada só na memória do browser e depois compara se a primeira imagem e as seguintes têm o mesmo `src`. Retorna `true` se todos tiverem, e `false` se pelo menos um não tiver.

Comment: concorda que ao invés de fazer `qtdDiferentes++` tu poderia fazer direto um `return true` e fora do for fazer um `return false`? :)

Comment: @MaiconCarraro é isso é bem melhor, obrigado.